# DataSet Relations or linq searching for better performance?

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

We have two tables:
**Parent**
  ID: Integer //Primary Key
  Name: String

**Child**
  FK: Integer //Reference to Parent.ID
  MoreInfo: String

Parent has 100,000 rows, Child has 10,000 rows (a lot of the rows in parent are not used in child)

Currently we do:

```
MyDS.Relations.Add("PC", MyDS.Tables["Parent"].Columns["ID"],
                         MyDS.Tables["Child"].Columns["FK"]);
foreach (DataRow drChild in MyDS.Tables["Child"].AsEnumerable())
  DataRow drParent = drChild.GetParentRows(MyDS.Relations["PC"]).FirstOrDefault();
```

We were thinking of changing to just searching manually with Linq:

```
foreach (DataRow drChild in MyDS.Tables["Child"].AsEnumerable())
  DataRow drParent = MyDS.Tables["Parent"].AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(
                                   drParent => drParent["ID"] == drChild["FK"]);
```

The table Child is iterated through only once and then the data set is disposed of. Anyone have any experiences using one method or the other - is creating the relationship in method1 a time waste if it is only used once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the relationship is definitely NOT a waste of time.

Whenever evaluating two potential solutions to a problem, you should always compare the cost/time of each option. From there you can usually make a call as to which choice is better. One thing to keep in mind is that the DataRelation exists to optimize these types of lookups.

If the DataRelation is being added to an existing table, approximately 125ms are required to add the relation (create the required hash to map parent/child rows via Datakeys).

To lookup EVERY parent row for each of the 10,000 child rows using the DataRelation required only 70ms, where using only the Linq approach documented above required over 4 minutes.

When you think about it, this makes sense as the first will iterate over the 10,000 child rows and use the DataRelation's mapped Datakeys to lookup the parent row (Doesn't need to iterate over all 100,000 parents). However, the second solution must traverse each child row (10,000) and search through 100,000 parent rows to find the suitable match (10,000 x 100,000 = 1,000,000,000).